# A higher dimensional generalization of cylindrical coordinate system?

Tags: spheres, cylindrical-coordinates

Does a higher dimensional generalization of a cylindrical coordinate system exist such that there is $N$ scalar dimensions and $M$ polar dimensions, and consequently does there exist a higher-dimensional generalization of a sphere characterized by $N$ lattitudinal and $M$ longitudinal dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I am confident that what you propose can be achieved. For example in four dimensional space $(x,y,z,t)$ one may introduce these coordinate systems:

- use 4-dimensional spherical coordinates
- keep $x$ cartesian, use spherical coordinates instead of $y,z,t$
- keep $x,y$ cartesian, use polar coordinates instead of $z,t$
- use polar coordinates for $x,y$ and also for $z,t$.

Note that the first has $1$ length and $3$ angles, the second and fourth have $2$ of each and the third has $3$ lengths and $1$ angle. As long as each point in four-dimensional space is uniquely defined, the choice of coordinate system is free.

Comment: Thank you. The systems you described are various methods higher dimensional Euclidean space can be mapped, which may lose generality, while the system that I'm seeking does not necessarily require Euclidean space, and a spheroid within this system is not necessarily a hypersphere. It may very well be case that such a spheroid can only exist or is identical to one in Euclidean space, in which case your methods would appear sufficiently generalized. Perhaps there's some sort of complex or hypercomplex construction that would be geometrically equivalent to what I'm looking for?